# Как правильно распределить парсинг ? Часто 503 ошибка

Tags: php, парсер

Всем привет.
У меня есть база аккаунтов в вк около 100штук, и я собираю по ним информацию скриптом, скрипт общается по АПИ с ВК, и записывает данные ко мне в базу периодически, раз в 5-10 минут. 
На один аккаунт уходит около 5-10 запросов каждые 5минут когда крон запускается, получается так, что когда запускается крон то у меня виснет сайт , выдавая ошибку 503.

Я дума это из-за того, что в каждом акке много запросов (5-10 в зависимости от условий), и когда включается крон - то сайт виснет с ошибкой 503...

Как правильно организовать парсинг данных, чтобы не вылетало такое? 
Спасибо

Comment: вы логи то для начала посмотрите?

Comment: а вы случаем не используете `file_get_contents`?

Comment: @teran смотрел конечно, 503 через раз статус

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный нет, через curl + proxy